# MS SQL Server: Documenting a database with no constraints

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a legacy system right now with a rather large MS-SQL database. The database has been growing and changing for ~20 years, but they've never put constraints in any of their tables. So, if you know that a table is on the many side of a join, the only way to discover that is to plumb through the stored procs and see how it's used (thanks SQL Search!).

Can anyone think of a way to document the relationships at least SEMI-automatically? The only thing I can think of is to write a console app which traverses the stored procs and notices where the joins are.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Are  there are least primary keys? If the names of the columns being joined are consistent or have a pattern you might be able to use sys.columns and sys.objects as a starting point.

Comment: I've done work a few times where stored procedure and view code SPL/DDL is pulled down and analyzed for relationships and lineage analysis. What you end up building is a light-weight SQL parsing engine to get the details you need out of the code. The output often takes the form a child/parent hierarchy that can often be highly cyclical for legacy or long-in-the-tooth systems like this. It's a giant pain in the rear, but also, in my opinion, a reasonable approach.

Comment: I would also expect to not walk away from such an effort with 100% accuracy, but rarely is that level of accuracy necessary for migration or lineage analysis or whatever end game you are aiming for.

Comment: Yes, there are primary keys, and there's about 90% conformity between a column name in the FK and the one in the PK.

Comment: Given the naming consistency you should be able to figure out about 90% of the foreign key relationships fairly easily then. As @JNevill said though, expect there to be quite a bit missing still. And possibly some false positives. You should be able to copy your databases to a test server though for analysis and testing. You can setup your foreign keys there to ensure that not just logical keys are present but there isn't data that violates the foreign keys as well.